# How to unescape amp; in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, console, escaping

Say I have this string `java&amp;script`, how can I convert this to `java&script`?

In the console of Google Chrome this doesn't work

```
var str="java&amp;script";
var str_esc=escape(str);
var str_unc = unescape(str_esc)
console.log(str_esc)
console.log(str_unc)
```

but this seems to work just fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var str="java&amp;script";
var str_esc=escape(str);
document.write(str_esc + "<br>")
document.write(unescape(str_esc))

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `java%26amp%3Bscript
VM3307:5 ` and 
`java&amp;script`
im getting the same string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could decode the entity with a function that drops the string into a textarea, and then pulls the value from that, like so:

```js
function htmlEntityDecode(str){
    var txt = document.createElement('textarea');
    txt.innerHTML = str;
    
    return txt.value;
}

var str = htmlEntityDecode("java&amp;script");

console.log( str );
```

Or even simpler, if it really is just that one case, why not just use a simple [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method on it?

```js
var str = 'java&amp;script';
str = str.replace('&amp;', '&');

console.log( str );
```

But if you have more than one instance, you would need to have a [global replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_global_and_ignore_with_replace()):

```js
var str = 'java &amp; script and script &amp; java';
str = str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');

console.log( str );
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to convert from an input string of say `"java&amp;script"` to `"java&script"` can be achieved via the regular expression `&amp;` passed to the [the `string#replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var inputStr="java&amp;script&amp;jj";

/* 
match any occourance of &amp; in the string and replace
with &. Use the gi to cause replacement to happen irrespective
of case (i) and globally across all occurances of &amp; 
in the string (g).
*/
var unescapedStr = inputStr.replace(/&amp;/gi, '&');

console.log(unescapedStr);
```